# How to get column name from JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

My code:

```
empDet emp = repository.findByActiveFlag("Y");
```

Here empDet is a entity with 3 columns:

1. empid
2. empName
3. ActiveFlag

Table with 10 rows so i will use foreach

```
emp.forEach(e-> {
---mycode---
---and here i got values--

});
```

Now my question is how to get Column name from Jpa or foreach loop

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "columns"? JPA is an Object Relational Mapping framework. So what you get is a list of Objects of your Entity Type. JPA already maps the columns to your entities properties. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have object of Entity class (empDet) in JPA then from that object you can get the all properties of that class.

As you know in JPA class represent table in database and properties represent columns of that table.

**if you have an object of empDet e.i emp**

```
empDet emp=repository.findByActiveFlag("Y");

Field[] members = emp.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field member:members){
            System.out.println(member.getName());
        }
```

Comment: Now How to get Value of that field                                                                                 
Field[] members = emp.getClass().getDeclaredFields();                                                                        for(Field member:members){
                if(member.getName().contentEquals("empName")==true) {                                       ----here i want to display value of that field                                                                             }}